# 45204 - Chat Channel Not Found

Tags: twilio

I was trying to create chat tasks via REST API, I successfully created channel, members, messages and tasks, however, when I tried to accept the task through **Twilio Flex** agent desktop, I always get error message:

> Failed to add worker to the chat channel.

In Debugger, I found that an error was logged as

> 45204 - Chat Channel Not Found.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

Thanks,

Yiqin

Comment: Are you creating the channel in the correct chat service, that is, the one that Flex is using too?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and yes, i used correct chat service id that is used by flex. In my case everything worked fine and all i needed is to remove this notification.

this can be done this way:

```
flex.Notifications.registeredNotifications.delete("notificationId")
```

Notification ids can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/notifications-framework#default-standard-notifications)

In my and your case id is ChatOrchestrationAddToChatChannelFailed, so final code looks like:

```
flex.Notifications.registeredNotifications.delete("ChatOrchestrationAddToChatChannelFailed")
```

source: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/notifications-framework#turn-off-standard-notifications